# how to give color to a slicer tile when selecting in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I like to shed blue when selecting Options in my slicer tile in PowerBi report, How can I do that?

Please see below picture for sample

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the default slicer in Power BI, there is no way to change the colour of the text based on selection. You can change the colour and font, but it will apply to all the text, selected or not.